# Calculate confidence given threshold in python

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I predict that A is 55%, standard deviation of 3%

How can I calculate the likelihood that A is above 50%?

Sorry for the basic question, but having trouble googling this.

Comment: Are you asking about the *statistical methodology*, or how to implement it from a programming standpoint?

Comment: how to implement it from a programming standpoint

Comment: I think it makes more sense to say that A has a mean of 55% and a standard deviation of 3%

Answer (score 0):

Someone with statistics background might answer you better... BUT,

If you assume you have a [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution), the probability that A is below 50% is given by the [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) of that distribution. To calculate the probability that A is above 50%, subtract 1 from it.

Calculation using scipy ([relevant docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html)):

```
from scipy.stats import norm

prob_lower50 = norm.cdf(0.50, loc=0.55, scale=0.03)
prob_higher50 = 1 - prob_lower50

print(prob_higher50)
# 0.9522
```